# Printing string inside nested hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I have been trying to learn the ropes of ruby for a Rails project that I picked up. I have C++ experience but am still learning my way around Ruby, so I will apologize now for not understanding Ruby and its nuances.

I have a hash that has elements containing another hash of strings...

```
def directors = {
   gm: { pos: "General Manager", email: "123@abc.com" },
   prod: { pos: "Production Director", email: "456@def.com" },
   support: { pos: "Support Director", email: "789@xyz.com" }
}
end
```

Within html I am able to run ruby code to access and output each respective string individually...

```
<%= directors[:gm][:pos] %>
<%= directors[:gm][:email] %>
<%= directors[:prod][:pos] %>
<%= directors[:prod][:email] %>
<%= directors[:support][:pos] %>
<%= directors[:support][:email] %>
```

This is a tedious and manual way to obtain and output every single element. I am attempting to write this in a more concise manner and in a way so that it will always display every element regardless of knowing how many elements are in each. I can write `directors.each` to call each element inside directors, but I need to again access each element inside of each director element. This is the best code I could come up with, but is not syntactically correct.

```
<% directors.each do |director| %>
   <% "#{director}" do |info| %>
      <%= dirs[:"#{director}"][:"#{info}"] %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display the nested hash, you can do so like this:

```
<% directors.each do |_internal_name, details| %>
  Position: <%= details[:pos] %>
  Email:  <%= details[:email] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use `each_value` if you're not going to use the hash key.

Comment: This assumes that you know what details (pos, email, etc.) each director has attributed to them, which in my case I do. This is a super elegant solution to my problem and I really appreciate the fast response!